# Can you change the R default table length when outputting with the DT package?

Tags: r, shiny, dt, flexdashboard

In R DT you can [define the table control elements](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/options.html) with code such as:

```
# only display the table, and nothing else
library(DT)
datatable(mtcars, options = list(dom = 't'))
```

The `t` above [is a DOM](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom). The DOM element `l` controls the [length changing input control](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom), basically how long your table will be. It looks like this.

[image: show entries selection]

This [length changing input control](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) defaults to a value of 10. How can I change this default value to 25, 100, perhaps even "All"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change it to 3 by `datatable(mtcars, options = list(dom = 't', pageLength = 3))`.

This will get you your desired results:

```
datatable(mtcars, options = list(dom = 't',
  lengthMenu = list(c(25, 100, -1), c('25', '100', 'All')),
  pageLength = 25
))
```

Answer (score 12):

We can set *iDisplayLength*:

```
datatable(mtcars, options = list(iDisplayLength = 25))
```

[image]

Related post:

- [Datatable only display 10 rows, when 50 asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37214235/datatable-only-display-10-rows-when-50-asked)

Answer (score -1):

Oh my, poke and hope until you find the secret combo, setting `pageLength` does nothing until you set `scrollY` to `TRUE`.

```
options = list(pageLength = 10, scrollY = TRUE)
```